# How to specify area to copy? C# WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datagrid, copy

I have Copy button near each of the row, and I want the text contained in the row near button to be copied when the button is pressed.

I can't understand how to specify what needs to be copied by pressing a button?

Image of table, and what exactly I want to copy: [image: here is picture]

Comment: Row's DataContext is basically what you want, since that is your item. How do you set your Button Click handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the `ApplicationCommands.Copy` command. This command is handled by the `DataGrid`. It will automatically copy the selected row to the clipboard.

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order" Binding="{Binding Order}" />

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Copy Action">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="Copy" 
                  Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```